# My state is changing without launching any action?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, state

I have a test to be dilevered today, and there is something that is blocking me, I don't why my state is changing at all, I have only two reducers and I don't understand what's happening.

Well here is my first reducer :

```
import update from "immutability-helper";

export default function parametersReducer(
  state = { pages: 10, interval: 20, pageActive: 0 },
  action
) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "PARAMETERS_CHANGE_PAGES":
      alert("Enrigistré");
      return update(state, { pages: { $set: action.payload } });
    case "PARAMETERS_CHANGE_INTERVAL":
      alert("Enrigistré");
      return update(state, { interval: { $set: action.payload } });
    case "PARAMETERS_CHANGE_ACTIVE_PAGE":
      return update(state, { pageActive: { $set: action.payload } });
    default:
      console.log(state);
      return state;
  }
}
```

And he is the second one :

```
import update from "immutability-helper";
import Axios from "axios";

export default function getTasksReducer(state = [], action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "GET_TASKS":
      console.log(action.paylaod);
      return "ok";
    case "GET_TASKS8first":
      console.log(action.paylaod);
      return "ok";

    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

I am still not using the second one, so only the default that can work, and here is what I log in my component :

```
 componentDidMount() {
   console.log(this.props);
   /*this.props.manageTasks("GET_TASKS_FIRST", {
    page: this.props.paramaters.pageActive,
    size: this.props.parameters.pages
   });*/
}
```

And here what I do to get the data in the component :

```
function mapStateToProps(state) {
  console.log(state);
  return { parameters: state.paramaters };
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return bindActionCreators({ manageTasks: manageTasks }, dispatch);
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Datatable);
```

Here is my combineReducers :

```
import { combineReducers } from "redux";
import reducerGlobReducer from "../reducerGlob";
import parametersReducer from "../Components/Parameters/Redux/parametersReducer";
import getTasksReducer from "../Components/Data/Datatable/redux/reducers/getTasksReducer";

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  parameters: parametersReducer,
  tasks: getTasksReducer
});

export default rootReducer;
```

What I am waiting to see is the default data in my parameters reducer, instead I am gettig undefined, I first get them but the state changes from line 1 to 2 :

```
Object : {parameters: {pages: 10, interval: 20, pageActive: 0}, tasks: []}
Object : {parameters: undefined, manageTasks: ƒ () }
```

I dont know why tasks is no longer there and why, Any help would be much appreciated.

If there is something you want me to add in the code, please ask and I will provide it.

Comment: could it be that `paramaters` !== `parameters` ? The typo i mean ?

Comment: Huh ? Don't get it ?

Comment: In `mapStateToProp` you have `return { parameters: state.paramaters };` The `state.paramaters` has an `a` instead of an `e` (*the third `a`*) so it would be returning `undefined`.

Comment: IN addition to above suggestion, can you add your combine reducers code here?

Comment: Both of you are right, I changed the typo and it worked but I still have manageTask property in the state, I don't get this, Yes, I will add combine reducders

Comment: @DehandeCroos I added it

Comment: manageTasks come from bind action creators

Comment: Yeah ? how to solve that then, Because clearly I want to see my state there not something else

Comment: The second log you see is not the `state`. It is the `props` of the component and it should contain the `manageTasks`